# Scroll on body when scrolling on fixed element and vice versa

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this div:

```
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  background: #222;
  height: 100%;
  width: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

An then I have the page content:

```
.content{
  width: calc(100% - 280px);
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 280px;
}
```

The content inside `.content` vary with each page, so sometimes the page is larger and sometimes it isn't. But there's a problem, if the sidebar doesn't fit the viewport, it appears a scrollbar. I want to achieve three things:

- Remove the scrollbar (i.e. make it invisible).
- That when you    scroll on `.content`, you also scroll on
  `.sidebar`.
- That when you    scroll on `.sidebar`, you also scroll on
  `.content`.

How can achieve this? even using jQuery, is there a way of making this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really appropriate for SO. There are too many possible answers for this general question.

Answer (score 0):

Put both in a container DIV, give them both `overflow-y: visible` and give the container `overflow-y: auto`. Then the container will scroll when any of the two elements in it is higher than the container.

Ah - and remove the `position: fixed`from the sidebar...